# ARC: Object - Delegate relationship

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I am developing an ***ARC enabled*** project. From a view controller I am pushing *MyClass*,

```
- (void)pushMyClass {
     MyClass *myClass = [[MyClass alloc] init];
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:myClass animated:YES];
}
```

After doing some operations I am popping MyClass. The problem here is that ***MyClass is not getting deallocated***. Following is how the classes look.

/* MyHelperClassDelegate */

```
@protocol MyHelperClassDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)helperDidFinishHelping:(MyHelperClass *)helper;
@end
```

/* MyHelperClass Interface */

```
@interface MyHelperClass : NSObject {
    __weak id <MyHelperDelegate> delegate;
}

@property(nonatomic, weak) id<MyHelperDelegate> delegate;

- (void)startHelping;

@end
```

/* MyHelperClass Implementation */

```
@implementation MyHelperClass

@synthesize delegate;

- (void)dealloc {
    delegate = nil;
}
```

/* MyClass */

```
@interface MyClass : UIViewController <MyHelperClassDelegate> {
    MyHelperClass *helper;
}

@implementation MyClass {

    - (void)dealloc {
        helper.delegate = nil;
    }

    - (void)getHelp {
        helper = [MyHelperClass new];
        helper.delegate = self;
        [helper startHelping];
    }

    - (void)helperDidFinishHelping:(MyHelperClass *)helper {
    }
}
```

*MyHelperClass* calls a web service using *NSMutalbleURLRequest* & *NSURLConnection* to fetch some data and saves it to user defaults.

One thing to notice here is, if I comment the line *helper.delegate = self;*, then MyClass gets deallocated.

What to do to make MyClass get deallocated when it is popped out of navigation controller?

Thanks.

Comment: You've included a lot of code that seems to have nothing to do with this MyClass instance you're asking about and very little that does relate to it. What does this MyHelperClass thing have to do with anything? I think either you need to be more clear about what your code is actually doing or you need to include more relevant code.

Comment: If you take out the `helper.delegate = self` line, does it ever become deallocated? If the behaviour doesn't change, then the problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: have you added a breakpoint or nslog statement to dealloc to verify that its being called?

Comment: @Ash Furrow, Yes. If I don't set the delegate, then MyClass gets deallocated. Thanks.

Comment: @andrewlattis, Yes. I added breakpoints. Its not getting there. Thanks.

Comment: "if I comment the line helper.delegate = self;, then MyClass gets deallocated" - Yes, but that proves nothing. If you comment that line, then `[helper startHelping]` is never called. But perhaps that is exactly where the extra retain happens. Any NSNotification registrations? Any repeating NSTimers? Those are the sorts of things that can get you into a retain cycle before you know what hit you...

Comment: @matt, Why [helper startHelping] when I don't set the delegate? Let me check for timers and notifications. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks everyone. MyClass was retained by another class. There was no problem with MyHelperClass. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your delegate code looks correct (except your use of an ivar, you don't show a @synthesize so you may have _delegate and delegate both). Its quite likely that something else is retaining MyClass. What I suggest you do is add a NSLog to your MyClass dealloc. Then push it, and immediately hit the back button and see if its dealloc'd or not. If not, then take a hard look at what you do in viewDidLoad et al and start commenting out sections of that code until you can get the dealloc.

Also, I assume you don't keep a strong reference in the class that pushes the MyClass object.

Comment: Your answer helped me get there. Another view was retaining my class. Thank you. And thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Chuck that one cannot say much from the code provided. But one reason why the `MyClass` object is not deallocated might be that it is retained by your `helper` object since `delegate` is declared as `strong`, and the `MyClass` object has the property `helper` also declared as strong. In this case you had a retain cycle, and none of them can be released.

Comment: Hi @Reinhard Männer, I have edited my question. Please see if could help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The trick could possibly lie within the fact that you use `NSURLConnection`. It is not specified how you use this class with the code that you've provided, but please note the special considerations referenced in the [NSURLConnection class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURLConnection/initWithRequest%3adelegate%3a):

> **Special Considerations:** During the download the connection maintains a
>   strong reference to the delegate. It releases that strong reference
>   when the connection finishes loading, fails, or is canceled.